# Unity in editor mode, OnGUI not called every frame

Tags: editor, unity-game-engine

I've created a button which is activated by selecting the option from the gameobject menu. This button does nothing but disappear upon clicking on it. However, theres always a delay between clicking on the button and it disappearing from the screen in game view. Can anyone help me with this please?

```
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class TestButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
       private static bool _setButton = false;

       [MenuItem("GameObject/TestButton")] 
       static void Init()
       {
        _setButton = true;
       }

       void OnGUI()
       {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(100, 0, 300, 100));
        if (_setButton)
        {
           if (GUILayout.Button("TEST BUTTON"))
           {
              _setButton = false;           
           }
           GUILayout.EndArea();
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: Did you run it in game mode or in editor mode?

Comment: I ran your code and there's no lag.